# Error running cron in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cron, crontab

Noticed in our error_log file is showing this below

```
[09-Feb-2016 16:55:02 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SCRIPT_NAME in /home/USERNAME/public_html/cron.php on line 40
[09-Feb-2016 16:55:02 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SCRIPT_FILENAME in /home/USERNAME/public_html/cron.php on line 41
```

on line 40 and 41 of the cron.php is this

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
```

anyone any ideas why its not running ?

Comment: What is the output of `crontab -l` ? Perhaps you are using the wrong binary for php.

Comment: Output of the cron is this below running every minute 

php -q /home/USERNAME/public_html/cron.php

Answer (score 1):

You'd mind `$_SERVER` variables are different if you run php in a web request or as a command line script (as your case)

Running php as command line script both variables should exist, unless you are running php-cgi. You should add `print_r($_SERVER);exit;` in `cron.php` file to see what's happening, and then hardcode that variables, if needed

More info here https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/11551